# 12.04 LTS server - no wifi

Tags: networking

Someone installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for me on my Lenovo S210 IdeaPad but there's no WIFI access.
and I can't ping anything other than the static IP.

```
lspci -nnk |grep - e ":" -e driver |grep ath
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

nm-tool  shows wlan0 "state" is disconnected but I see valid entries in Wireless Access Points. Significant?

Any idea how to fix whatever is broken?

Comment: Edit your question and add the the output of `nm-cli`, `iwconfig`, `ping -c2 4.2.2.2`, `ping -c2 google.com`, `ifconfig`.

Comment: nm -cli ->supported targets: elf64-x86-64 elf32-i386 elf32-x86-64 a.out-i386-linux pei-i386 pei-x86-64 elf64-l10m elf64-k1om elf64-little elf64-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex

Comment: iwconfig -> eth0 no wireless extensions   lo no wireless extensions   wlan0  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any Tx-Power=16 dBm     Retry  long limit:7  RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off   Power Management:off

Comment: PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data. FROM 169.x.x.x icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreadable FROM 169.x.x.x. ... Dest. Host Unreadable       ping: unknown host google.com

Comment: collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  RX bytes:183592(183.5 KB) TX bytes(183592 (183.5 KB)        wlan0  Link encap:Ethernet HWaddrr... UP BROAD MULTIC MTU:5000 Metric:1 RX pack:0 err:0..frame:0 TX pack:0...carrier:0  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)   wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr:... inet addr:169... Bcast: 169... Mask:... UP BCAST 1500 MTU Metric:1

Comment: **[Edit] your question and add the information**. As you can see, is difficult to read in comments.

Comment: nmtool shows wlan0 "disconnected" but "Wireless Access Points" entries are there correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. nm-tool gave me the hint.  wlan0 was disconnected but the correct wireless network entry was listed. Simply connecting to the wireless network and supplying the correct p/w did the trick.